# Mysql regex search over an array of phone numbers

Tags: mysql, regexp-substr

Need help in executing a query over a customer database on a field named phone.

```
select * from customers where phone REGEXP '123456|565834'
```

I need a way to select the matched portion of regex matched in select clause.
The final results should be something like

```
 Name      Matched      Phone

 Naveen    123456      12345678
 Naveen2   123456     123456789
 Arun      565834       9565834
 Arun2     565834      10565834
```

P.S. This has to be one query and there is no other unique key to be grouped by with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSTR` function of MySQL.
Ex.  `INSTR(regex, phone)`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('123456|565834',INSTR('123456|565834',phone),10)  
FROM customers 
WHERE phone REGEXP '123456|565834';
```

[Doc: INSTR function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php)

Comment: used instr to get index and the used subtring to get the match portion.
This would do for time being. Thanks @rahul

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `CASE` expression here:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    CASE WHEN Phone REGEXP '123456' THEN '123456'
         WHEN Phone REGEXP '565834' THEN '565834' END AS Matched,
    Phone
FROM customers
WHERE
    phone REGEXP '123456|565834';
```

Note that you don't necessarily need to use `REGEXP` in this case, `LIKE` probably would have sufficed.  But using `REGEXP` is easier to read IMO, and also it lets you handle more complex logic, should you need to in the future.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegelsien. Its good suggestion. What if i have any array of 1000 phone numbers to be looked up and accordingly get the matched portion. Certainly we can construct a case when statement string and add to the query dynamically but is there any other approach ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not constrained to only use mysql, then may try with shell script + mysql to pass the map values and search - Not sure understood the requirement correctly.

```
search="5672C";
mysql <connection details> -e "select fields, \"$search\" as matched from customers where phone like \"%$search%\";"
```

We  can loop the map strings and achieve.